# vb.net RegEx replace

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a regex that searches an input string looking for a possible SSN. That part all works great, but I want to be able to replace what I detect as a SSN with a string of asterisks.

For example, if `123456789` is my SSN to replace and I use `"123456789, 00123456789000, 1234567899999"` as the input string, I just want to end up with `"*********, 00123456789000, 1234567899999"` but everything I am trying is affecting the second and third string elements as well.

I was thinking that I could use my initial search pattern as the same replace pattern but also make sure there wasn't a digit on each side of it but I can't get it to work.

This is my search pattern and it works fine:

```
Dim reg As New Regex("\d{3}\D{0,1}\d{2}\D{0,1}\d{4,}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure there are word boundaries before and after the pattern using `\b`...

```
"\b\d{3}\D{0,1}\d{2}\D{0,1}\d{4}\b"
```